# Postfix virtual mailboxes, catch-all, relay only a few of them to another server based on recipient address

Tags: postfix, email-server

I'm using Postfix as a main MX server, connected to internet. On LAN I have MS Exchange, not accessible from internet.

Postfix works fine with virtual mailboxes, Dovecot for POP3/IMAP etc. I'm using catch-all `virtual_alias_maps` - have `@mydomain.cz` -> myreal@email.cz.

I want to forward mails for specific recipient addresses to Exchange server. Normally it's done with `transport_maps`, but when I use catch-all virtual alias, mail is sent to myreal@email.cz and not processed with `transport_maps`.

Is it possible to use `transport_maps` with catch-all `virtual_alias_maps`?

Interesting parts of Postfix configuration:

```
transport_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-transports.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

MySQL .cf files:

```
query = SELECT password FROM virtual_users WHERE email='%u' LIMIT 1
query = SELECT destination FROM virtual_aliases WHERE source='%s'
query = SELECT 1 FROM virtual_domains WHERE name='%s'
query = SELECT 1 FROM virtual_users WHERE email='%s'

table = transport
select_field = transport
where_field = domain
additional_conditions = and active = '1'
```

[image: Schema of the problem]

Comment: myreal@email.cz is handled by exchange server? Add output of the 'postconf -n' to the question

Comment: No, it's not. It's independent e-mail address. By Exchange server is handled for ex. user1@mydomain.cz. I simply don't want to rely on exchange server to handle all e-mails (whole domain), so I send them to Postfix first and only a few users use Exchange.

Comment: I've added an image of the problem.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/536001/how-to-route-mail-in-postifix-based-on-recipient-address?rq=1